# Calculating the win percentage every round

Tags: python, class, methods

Imagine there are two players playing bowling. The program keeps track of the score and the success percentage (means the amount of scores entered which > 0p, i.e. the player didn't fail his/her turn)

For example:

```
Scoreboard:
A: 0 p, hit percentage 0.0
B: 0 p, hit percentage 0.0

Enter the score of player B of throw 2: 2
Scoreboard:
A: 0 p, hit percentage 0.0
B: 2 p, hit percentage 100.0

Enter the score of player A of throw 3: 3
Scoreboard:
A: 3 p, hit percentage 50.0
B: 2 p, hit percentage 100.0

Enter the score of player B of throw 4: 0
Scoreboard:
A: 3 p, hit percentage 50.0
B: 2 p, hit percentage 50.0
```

I could implement the program to take turn of the player and add up the point, but having difficulties in the percentage part, how to switch the percentage of each player. Thank you so much for your help!

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name
        self.__point = 0

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_points(self):
        return self.__point

    def add_points(self,point):
        self.__point += point
    
    *def percentage(self, point):
        ?
    def get_per(self):
        return self.__percentage* 
        
def main():
    player1 = Player("A")
    player2 = Player("B")
    throw = 1
    while True:
        if throw % 2 == 0: # if throw is an even number
            in_turn = player1
        else: # else throw is an odd number
            in_turn = player2
        pts = int(input("Enter the score of player " + in_turn.get_name() +
                        " of throw " + str(throw) + ": "))
        in_turn.add_points(pts)
        in_turn.percentage(pts)
        print("Scoreboard after throw " + str(throw) + ":")
        print(f"{player1.get_name()}: {player1.get_points()} p, hit percentage {player1.get_per():.1f}")
        print(f"{player2.get_name()}: {player2.get_points()} p, hit percentage {player2.get_per():.1f}")
        throw += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two more attributes (say `__number_of_rounds` and `__successful_hits`) to your class. In your `add_points` method always increment `__number_of_rounds` by 1, and increment `__successful_hits` only if `point > 0`. For example:

```
def __init__(self,name):
    self.__name = name
    self.__point = 0
    self.__number_of_rounds = 0
    self.__successful_hits = 0
```

and

```
def add_points(self,point):
    self.__point += point
    self.__number_of_rounds += 1
    if point > 0:
        self.__successful_hits += 1
```

then

```
def get_per(self):
    if self.__number_of_rounds > 0:  # Check for division by zero
        return 100 * self.__successful_hits / self.__number_of_rounds
    else:
        return 0.0
```

You don't need a separate `percentage` method as `add_points` can do both. Besides you can't trust the consumer to call both methods.

Comment: Great answer. I have one question, why do your attribute names start with double leading underscore? Is that a convention for class attributes?

Comment: @joostblack Actually the Python convention for private members is a single underscore (`_`). See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private My use of double underscores (`__`) is just to be consistent with OP's original implementation.